# Windows 8 app Image source from another assembly

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have my Windows 8 app separate to multiple projects and I am trying to show images in my view project (Project.View.WindowsStore):

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Project.App.WindowsStore/Assets/Images/Background/dark_blue_1366_768.jpg">
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Project.App.WindowsStore/Assets/Images/logo.png" />
```

Both are "working". They show my images in VS designer but when I tried it to debug on my local computer and on my remote tablet and in both the images are missing. So what is problem with paths to images? Or should I set something more then just add images and path to them? My images are set to Content and Copy-if-newer.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ms-resource:///` protocol by setting build property to content or embedded resource ?

Comment: I tried to set Build Action to Content and Embedded Resource and nothing worked. Now I tried both options with ms-resource prefix and still nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the images of another project you can directly use.

Try the path as:

```
"ms-appx:///Assets/Images/logo.png"
```

and change the properties of `logo.png` to:

```
Build Action : Content

Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
```

Give a try. It will work.

Comment: It's really working. Thanks. The weird thing is that now it's not showing images in designer but when I run it, it's working.